# boost libraries size = 10.9GB?

Tags: boost, build, size

I've compliled  BOOST "boost_1_55_0" with visual studio

Source size is about 473 MB, after the build I got  a 10.9 GB folder...

Is it normal ? This is more than windows 7 size...

Thanks.

Comment: Delete bin.v2 folder, this is the intermediate output.

Comment: Hi, bin.v2 folder size is 7.49 GB I'll be happy to delete  it.
But is it completely useless ?

Comment: Yes. It contains intermediate MSVC output (object files, libs, pdbs etc). If you build with `stage` parameter, the built libraries are copied to `stage/lib` folder, and that's what you should use. By the way, take a look at this folder and whether you actually need all these libs and their variants. If not - build selectively.

Comment: yes I built with `stage` parameter and I'm using stage/lib.
@sehe told that I could speed up my rebuild if I kept **bin.v2**.
I'm a little confused...

Comment: He meant Boost developers, not users. Your own code doesnt see bin.v2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal.

It's big because you build all variants, and the intermediate files for all variants are kept (with all debug information). This is very helpful for incremental rebuilds with small changes (e.g. when doing development on a boost library), beause it will only build targets that are out of date.

Now, it's **not bigger than Windows 7**. Last time I checked, windows 7 64-bit clocked 30GiB on a clean installation. I happen to know, because I used to have SSDs of 30GiB :|

---

**Update** Linux Figures:

By the way, on my linux box my boost trees are 0.5-1GiB in size, but that's because I use `--build-dir=/tmp/build-boost` while building (and maybe it doesn't build quite as many variants on linux, by default).

The boost-modular tree is 1.3GiB on linux (or 1.7GiB on a 'well-worn' one that has been used to build several different versions).

Comment: you said "This is very helpful for incremental rebuilds with small changes"
Are you talking about intermediate files ?

Comment: @hughes Yes. I don't know what else it could refer to :)